# mysql get null value while Comparison beween columns

Tags: mysql

I think this is very simple,how to achieve this in single condition.

I have table with 3 columns

```
mysql> select ID,NEW_TIME,OLD_TIME from Table;
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   ID   | NEW_TIME          | OLD_TIME          |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 581318 |     1522726409000 |              NULL |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

and try the below query

```
select * from table where NEW_TIME > OLD_TIME;
```

It was showing empty.how to fetch these null rows also while comparing.

Comment: do you pass the arguments? or just the values in table

Comment: update my question, please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL IFNULL function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NEW_TIME > IFNULL(OLD_TIME,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `OR` condition on query with `IS NULL` check as: `OR OLD_TIME IS NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NEW_TIME > OLD_TIME OR OLD_TIME IS NULL;
```

Comment: yes, me too trying the same, but I want to achieve in single condition

Comment: Why do you need to have it in one condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NEW_TIME > IFNULL(OLD_TIME,0)
```